# Is it possible to collect 110 coins on Bombarded by Bob-ombs?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3, super-mario-advance-4, nintendo-e-reader

In *Super Mario Advance 4: Super Mario Bros. 3*, the e-Reader stage *Bombarded by Bob-ombs* has a strange coin-shaped block at the start that I've never seen before. Hitting the block adds a counter that decreases when you collect coins. The Super Mario Wiki claims that [collecting 110 coins on the stage will earn you 3 extra lives](https://www.mariowiki.com/Bombarded_by_Bob-ombs#Level_synopsis), but I couldn't find a source for this. I tried to confirm by playing the stage myself but was unable to find 110 coins.

Is it possible to collect 110 coins on *Bombarded by Bob-ombs*? If yes, does doing so after hitting the coin block actually earn you 3 extra lives?

[image: The yellow coin block on Bombarded by Bob-ombs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quality is very poor but [in this gameplay video](https://youtu.be/zjNdrC1v_p8?t=156) you can clearly see that it is possible to collect the 110 coins and doing so awards 3 extra lives as documented in the Wiki.

For historical purposes, this is the relevant frame in the video:

[image]